# Change browser from Edge to IE with Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm working on a website where (due to security settings in the users Windows desktops), the users cannot use the Edge browser.

Is there a work-around where I can 'redirect' the website to use Internet Explorer? In other words, ask it to perform the equivalent of run Internet explorer as an app and go to the same URL?

We will fix the issues on the website, but I don't want to get into the issues here, thanks.

-----edit-----

In this case the users have pre-packaged Windows 10 with non-standard security settings for Edge. Sadly I don't have control over the windows build and in a large company there are a number of hurdles before the corrected settings can be applied.

It's all well and good to let users choose their own browsers in normal situations, but in this specific case a solution is required.

I am happy to create a temporary "please use Internet Explorer page" but I was hoping a mime application type or other solution could suggest to the windows pc to run IE along with the same url the user is first accessing to make this more seamless.

Comment: You can not determine which browser should serve your content, End user will!

Comment: The 1990s called. They want their "Best viewed in IE" back

Comment: @Rayon this is only partially true. MSIE always supported a backward-compatibility mode. It sounds reasonable for them to include such a mode in a newer browser.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak and what you are saying is only partially true. The backwards compatibility modes that Microsoft have done have _always_ been imperfect: they'd either _not_ have a big that a previous version had or have _different_ bugs. So, say, switching IE10 into IE8 mode would never behave exactly like IE8 and it would just introduce yet more subtle bugs. So, even if you were to somehow convince the browser to fallback to legacy support (_if_ it even does that. It can very well not do it because it's never been a good solution), then it's not going to _be_ IE.

Comment: http://developer.telerik.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/best-viewed-with-ie.png

Comment: @vlaz I never claimed it to be perfect, nor did I advertise or suggest it. Which part of my comment exactly is wrong?

Comment: Hi guys - I have edited the question so the 'why' is more obvious. The Edge settings on the users PCs simply don't allow necessary file types to be accessed, and a fix for that is probably 3 months away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sites can't control whether to use IE11 or Edge, however Microsoft does allow specific sites to be white listed to only use IE11 using Group Policy. Here is Microsoft's page talking about it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/microsoft-edge/emie-to-improve-compatibility